# Execute complex command from bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working with kafka and I want to monitor topics. Basically I output several topics to stdout and to file for later review.
For single topic monitoring I came up with the following command:

```
${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytopic | \
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
      printf '[%s | %20s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "mytopic" "${line}";
    done | tee -a kafka.out
```

However, there're many topics to consume, so I'm trying to do something like

```
consumer=${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh
mapfile -t topics < <(${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list)
for i in ${topics[@]}; do
  xterm -T ${i} -e "my_command" &
done
tail -F kafka.out
```

where `my_command` is the above command. It doesn't work. I suspect I'm messing up with quotes, unfortunately I can't figure out how to apply them correctly

Comment: Why not make the first command an executable (eg `show_topic` that takes the topic as a parameter.  Then your `xterm` line becomes a simple `xterm -e "show_topic $i"` and you avoid the whole quoting mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store some text verbatim, it's usually easier with this syntax:

```
mycommand=$(cat << 'EOF'
"${KAFKA_HOME}/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh" --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic "$TOPIC" |
  while IFS= read -r line; do 
    printf '[%s | %20s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$TOPIC" "${line}";
  done | tee -a kafka.out
EOF
)
```

In `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, you can also make it:

```
mycommand=$(<<'EOF'
....
EOF
```

In `ksh93` that optimises out the exec of cat and the fork, while with `bash` only the exec (in `zsh`, it makes no difference).

In `mksh`:

```
mycommand=<<'EOF'
...
EOF
```

And then:

```
export TOPIC KAFKA_HOME
for TOPIC in "${topics[@]}"; do
  xterm -T "$TOPIC" -e "$mycommand" &
done
```

Here, I'd use `ts` to time-stamp the input (or do it in `gawk` or `perl` if `ts` is not available) instead of that very inefficient `while read` loop.

```
ts '[%F %T | mytopic]'
```

Comment: thanks a lot! and `ts` is much better, indeed